# React dev tools blank component

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

Hello does anybody knows what's wrong with my react dev tools? the components tab is blank [image: see photos]

Comment: I think you have an error. Check the console first. Also make sure your project is running.

Comment: @ravibagul91 nah that's not the error since i've access it using different devices and the elements normal showing in the component tabs, it didn't show only on one device. could it be something wrong with the chrome? but before it's normal

Comment: I resolved the problem by executing yarn global add react-devtools and then restarting Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem that others have encountered recently. There is a fix at: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16840

Comment: @Hilman, can you specify what exact comment worked for you? It seems to be a long thread, and there's a new React-dev tools package zipped. Did you install that?

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible." - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 30):

Open the DevTools and do a `ctrl+shift+p` and then `Reload DevTools`. Unless there is an error in your app, this should help. Or use the suggested shortcut `alt+r`

Comment: suprised that it worked :D

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the solution from @divakar

Windows:

Open the DevTools and do a `ctrl+shift+p` and then `Reload DevTools`. Unless there is an error in your app, this should help. Or use the suggested shortcut alt+r

MacOs users:

`Option + Command + J`, followed by `Command + Shift + P`.
Then `Reload DevTools`

[image: Reload dev tools]

Comment: Since this is fundamentally the same answer and just adds the Mac keyboard shortcuts, I think it'd be better to edit the original answer. That makes it much better for users since there's fewer answers to dig through.

Answer (score 0):

to whoever is running for this same reason.

I recently ran into this issue, what worked for me was to reinstall google chrome(the browser where I am using dev tools), then it worked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was unintalling react-devtools:

`npm uninstall -g react-devtools`, which I had installed globally;

and then re-installing it back as a dev-dependency:

`npm install react-devtools --save-dev`

and also don't forget to **reload** your app through the [React native debugger](http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/) after launching the react-devtools i.e `npx react-devtools`